# React: How to change the controls on the Radio button selection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In React, On page load, I am displaying four radio buttons. On Radiobutton mobile, when click, it will display phone number dropdown, and hide Email textbox. On Radio button Email, when click it will display Email textbox, and hide phone number dropdown. Dropdown and textbox only shown when radio button click. Please find my code, how this can be achieved?

https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-fire-r2rkzh

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('')

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form Id="custReviewForm">
        <input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value={selected}
onChange={setSelected}/>
        mobile:
        <br />
        <select name="phoneno" id="phonenumber">
          <option>111-111-1111</option>
          <option>222-222-2222</option>
          <option>333-333-3333</option>
          <option>444-444-4444</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value="optEmail" />
        Email:<br />
        <input type="textbox" id="txtEmail"  value="Email"/>
        <br /><input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value="optcode" />
        code
        <br /><input type="radio" id="html" name="options" value="optAddress" />
        address
        <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering

Comment: this question has been closed, but it needed a bit more explanation than the recommended link because you are missing more than one concept of how react works. have a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-butterfly-mb46my?file=/src/App.js:0-1729 for a working example